# Facebook OAuthException Code 191 - Invalid redirect (sometimes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth-2.0

I've been losing a lot of sleep about this and really don't know how to solve it.

The bug only affects a few of my users, sometimes after they have already signed up and want to login with Facebook again. One of my users submitted the following great screenshot that shows both the error and the link - when I try this from my computer, it works without problems, in any language.

[image: Screenshot]
The link on the button is:

```
http://www.thestudentranking.com/users/auth/facebook?locale=en
```

**Routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations"}
devise_for :users
```

**Setup in Facebook**
[image: Facebook app setup]

I'm not sure what I could try next to fix this. I read quite a few answers on SO, but these did not seem to help. It must be a common error, would really like to know what I am doing wrong.

**Update**
I tried setting the app details and site url to the following and will check whether this works.
[image: try]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the callbacks properly. I have uploaded one example application for this on GitHub which includes the Application configuration with screenshot. Please go through this example : [Omni_share_example](https://github.com/sonianand11/omniauth_share_example). Hope that would help you.

Comment: Thank you Anand, this is good suggestion. I've reviewed the github example, but you provide something for localhost. Can you give me an example screenshot for the site url for a production site? Is the one I created above correct? If yes, then I'm really happy and will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Please replace localhost with your url.

Comment: It's working after my update, don't hear about any problems any more and gaining users nicely. Thank you Anand for preparing that app. I'm sure other people might have the same problem I had, maybe you could add a picture like I did in the update to your example app to show an alternative. Kind regards, Michael